# How to get input from audio jack in Windows?

Tags: c++, c, audio, input

I'm attempting to create a Windows application that will allow the controls on earbuds/headphones that have them (such as the [Nokia Purity](http://www.puritybymonster.com/en/#page_in-ear) earbuds) to work on Windows. I would think that there are two ways to go about doing this:

1. Attempt to get some kind of input from the audio output jack
2. Plug the earbuds into the microphone jack, and then try and play music through there (while watching the microphone's input for whatever it is that the buttons do).

So, I'm starting off by trying the first option, which leads me to my question. Is there a way to get any kind of raw input from the audio jack in Windows? Is there a better way to do this? I'd like to use C#, but if it's only possible in C/C++ or another language, that would be fine as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such possibility. PC audio jacks are only two channels (stereo). Headphones with additional buttons use more than two channels to handle them.

Comment: ah, that's what I was worried the answer would be :\ thanks anyway!